# what is the wattage rating of a 2 watt resistor in oil?

Tags: power, resistors, power-dissipation

I have a termination resistor for a antenna and while it is rated at 300 watts, I opened it up and it is not capable of dissipating 300 watts as constructed.  It is in a PVC tube and has sufficient volume to allow filling with mineral oil.  But would like to know the increase in dissipation the termination will have.  It is made up of 22 each 5 watt resistors.  So has an initial power rating of 110 watts.

Comment: Despite the rumours, size does matter. If depends on the surface area of everything involved and the volume of the tube. Oil filled will be a lot better than air filled, but without numbers this question is unaswerable.

Comment: Unless the manufacturer is some no-name chinese fly by night operation, if it's rated at 300W, it is reasonably likely to be able to dissapate 300W, although a factor of two safety buffer is usually recommended.

Comment: Hams do this all the time for dummy loads. But your setup sounds a bit optimistic for the rated load. Google around and compare actual experiences- this is 'off label' use of the resistors most likely.

Comment: This is a thermodynamics problem and better left to experimentation. Make sure you don't exceed the temperature rating of the resistor

Answer (score 1):

You're asking if placing a normally air cooled device in mineral oil can create a three fold increase in power capacity.  I think that it's close, but yes.  You should easily achieve going from 110W to 300W.  Although bear in mind, that you would not want to run your 22 resistors at 5W in air.  They would get very hot.  The following is for a typical power resistor.  Look at the SBCH4/5 curve.  That's 250+ deg. C for 5W!  That's not good for your PVC case or your hand.

[image: surface temperature]

Mineral oil has 5 times the thermal conductivity of air and 1.7 times the specific heat capacity.  The enhanced conductivity will create a much bigger effective cooling area as the heat flows from the resistor cases to the outside of the PVC tube, which will then act as a much bigger radiator.  This is an example of what [three types of coolant](http://www.symscape.com/examples/rans/electronics-cooling-fluid-comparison-study) can do to a heat sink:-

[image: coolant evaluation]

That's a 8 fold improvement.  Please realise that the above heat flow software (Symscape) isn't Solidworks Flow Simulation, but it feels kinda right.  Also realise that the duty cycle will affect the overal temperature rise in the load.  So shorter bursts can use more power.  It's difficult to say what the temperature rise would be with a 100% 300W duty cycle run continuously.  Some dummy loads have metal cases with fins, so they're effectively oil filled radiators.

If running close to the edge is important and you've access to the internals, can I suggest one of these cheapo thermometers plunged into the oil?

[image: thermometer]

Mineral oil boils at 300+ deg.C.  That's not good for anything.

Comment: OK, Tanks to everyone.  I will take the most pessimistic approach and rate it at 3x not 5x until I can test it thermally.  The application is a product made for a T2FD antenna design variation.  I designed and built the 16:1 balun.  I just did not like the product the manufacturer made for the termination.  Hence, my query.  Thanks all.....

Answer (score 0):

Containment is not cooling.

What I see lacking from this plan is an ultimate heat sink; a way to dispose of the heat.  By filling the tube with oil you are only containing the heat. It will sit in the tube getting hotter and hotter, absent anything to carry the heat away.  So far you only seem to have

- Convection cooling through the skin of the tube.
- The latent heat of evaporation of the oil.  This method would consume your coolant and splatter oil all over the place.

Either one will work (reach thermal equilibrium) if the oil gets hot enough, but I think that would be a lot hotter than you'd want.  I would worry about the PVC melting.

I think the obvious solution is to use a pumped cooling system to a radiator, as are common with higher end PCs.  This would allow you to keep the cooling at sensible temperatures.

One way to get a high capacity radiator is hit a pick-n-pull auto junkyard and grab a radiator+electric fan assembly. Use the radiator or just the transmission cooler, which ia made for oil, however in the latter case you'd want to fill the radiator with coolant and plug the inlet and outlet, because the trans  cooler is an oil-water heat exchanger.

Comment: I agree the PVC tube sounds limiting.  The traditional ham radio solution is the "cantenna" - a gallon paint can type container with the RF connector built into the lid.  That gives both a lot of surface area to shed heat, and a lot of thermal mass of oil for brief use at high power levels.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I knew about the Cantenna, and it's perfect for transient loads.  The problem is duty cycle, I was under the impression OP was after 100% for extended periods.

Comment: The point was that there was enough surface area to run substantial powers continuously, as well as enough thermal mass to run high powers briefly.  As a crude guess, something like 100 watts (or perhaps more) as long as you want, and a kilowatt for 30 seconds.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yeah, those numbers would make sense.

Comment: Thanks all, the application is narrow duty cycle with high peaks, so Chris answer is appropriate.  If extended time is required, I will add external heat sink with thermal conductivity to the oil. I like the method PG&E does with the high power pole mounted transformers where the allow the hot oil to rise and pull in cooler oil from the bottom of the external radiators.  Thanks again.